# Is it useless to use "Dim" to declare a variable if I don't write an "as something" after it?

Tags: vba, excel

For example, are the following two codes the same? Is it unnecessary to use Dim if I don't write for example "as integer" after that?

```
Sub something()

MyNumber = 10

Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = MyNumber

End Sub
```

and

```
Sub something()

Dim MyNumber

MyNumber = 10

Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = MyNumber

End Sub
```

Comment: It is important.  If you don't specify what you want, VBA will declare it as a variant.  Research what that is.

Comment: You are correct both start as variant then it changes to integer, but you declare variable and use `option explicit` to ensure you are not mistyping the variable when using it multiple times.

Comment: Also explicitly declaring it as a type ensures that you is correctly and that you know how you are using it and what can be passed into it. It's also good practice to using some sort of naming convention. Like `Dim sName as String` or `lRow as Long` or even `vArrayName as Variant`. There are good and specific uses for each type, yet its best for memory and processing to use the *specific type* needed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you **Dim**ension a variable you are letting the compiler know that you are planning to use a certain amount of memory *in advance* of that variable being used. In most VBA programs on modern machines this wouldn't create a *huge* performance benefit, but is widely considered best practice.

One of the reasons that it is considered best practice is the *auto-capitalization* feature in the VBE which can help you as you're coding and debugging to spot any issues.

If you dimension a variable, and do the following:

```
Dim hWnd

hWnd = 1234
'// some more code....
hwnd = 2345
```

The VBE will automatically capitalize the `w` in the variable name and change it to `hWnd` - this can act as a small reassurance that you've got the right variable and not created a typo.

---

If you ***don't*** dimension a variable, you could easily find yourself in this kind of scenario:

```
hWnd = 1234
'// some code here
hwnd = 2345
```

In *this* scenario, the VBE will actually change the first occurrence of `hWnd` to `hwnd`. We then go on further to create a typo of `hnwd` and now our code looks like this:

```
hwnd = 1234
'// code here
hwnd = 2345
'// code here
hnwd = 3456
```

And suddenly you're scrolling through lines of code trying to find out why you're getting unexpected results.

---

***TO BE SAFE***

1. Use `Option Explicit`
2. Declare all variables `As` their respective data type or object. This also gives the added benefit of [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense)

Answer (score 1):

Good coding practice is to declare the variable and it's type.

Using "option Explicit" at the beginning of a module enforces this.

Anything not explicitly declared is declared by the system as type variant.  This is less efficient.

From a code maintenance standpoint, it is harder to maintain implicit code than it is explicit code.  20 years ago, a case could be made to be a bit more clever with your code and combine as many calculations on a single line as possible, but now processing, storage and memory are so cheap that maintainability has become the priority over efficiency.

So, it's not useless, but it could cause difficulties on your team if someone else needs to maintain your code.